# phpunit config file using wrong php.ini in vagrant

Tags: php, phpunit, vagrant, sublimetext2, xdebug

I have an application on a vagrant VM and am trying to implement PHPUnit in Sublime.

I got everything up and running and wanted to also install XDebug in order to utilize PHPUnit's code coverage functionality. That ended up being a huge hassle and I decided to uninstall XDebug. But now, PHPUnit (installed via composer on my VM) references the php.ini file on my local machine instead of the one in my VM.

How can I make it so that PHPUnit will reference the correct php.ini file?

Comment: How do you know it references php.ini on your local instead of the VM? I find it hard to believe. Most likely you're running your phpunit installed on the host, rather than the VM.

Comment: Hmm, I know it's referencing php.ini on my local because when I change the settings in that file (e.g. short_open_tag = Off) it affects the tests when they run. And I'm pretty sure I don't have phpunit installed on my local (`$ phpunit --version` gives me: `phpunit: command not found`).